# Installing R from CRAN Ubuntu repository: No Public Key Error

Tags: linux, r, apt

I am on R version 2.13 and would like to update to a newer version in order to use some packages that depend on R>= 2.14.

I have the line to my sources.list file as found described [here](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/).  I then navigate to the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and get the following error when trying to update R on the CRAN mirror closest to me:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> W: GPG error: http://lib.stat.cmu.edu oneiric/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9

Any idea how to debug this error?

Comment: search farther down the page you linked -- look for "SECURE APT", and follow the instructions there ...

Comment: Moreover, the line starts with *W* meaning it is a _warning_ only.

Comment: Further to @ben-bolker -- I met this problem myself and could not solve it, even when I followed the SECURE APT instructions. I found that I was behind a firewall at work that closed port 11371 and I could not download the secure key. This condition can be [tested here](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/). The only way I could perform this upgrade was by doing it at home, where I have access to my router.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Like @Ben Bolker commented (sorry I hijacked your commented, but the correct answer was not yet posted), in [the description](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/) of the debian package repo there is a section `secure apt` which says:

> SECURE APT
>
> The Debian backports archives on CRAN are signed with the key of
>   "Johannes Ranke (CRAN Debian archive) " with key
>   ID 381BA480. You can fetch this with
>
> gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-key 381BA480 or
>   alternatively, using another key server,
>
> gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-key 381BA480 If this doesn't
>   work, it might be due to a firewall blocking port 11371.
>   Alternatively, you can search for 0x381BA480 at
>   http://keyserver.noreply.org/ or http://pgp.mit.edu/ and copy the key block into a plain text
>   file, named, for instance, jranke_cran.asc.
>
> If receiving the key with gpg did work, you need to export it to a
>   text file
>
> gpg -a --export 381BA480 > jranke_cran.asc In both cases you need
>   to make the key known to the apt system by running
>
> apt-key add jranke_cran.asc as root.

If you have not already done this, this will probably fix your issue.

Comment: I don't mind you hijacking the comment at all.  I comment when I'm too lazy to post a full answer ...

Comment: Note that both this and @ManuelRamon's answer rely on an older key.  Substitute with whatever you get from the error message from `apt-get update`.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that the 'cut and paste'-option from the SECURE APT section works like a charm:
    Search for the key at http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/ (search for Michael Rutter) and copy the key to a plain text file, say key.txt. Then, feed the key to apt-key with

   sudo apt-key add key.txt

Comment: Question - this information is now outdated because the current public key is Michael Rutter as noted in the answer below.  Is it appropriate to edit this answer to reflect the new information?  What is the standard on StackExchange?

Answer (score 89):

The simplest solution that worked for me was from Emre Sahin in [this thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-update-problem-td4667122.html):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
```

Comment: the key in the marked answer doesn't seem to work for me. this one did though

Comment: +1 this worked for me, but note I needed to change the key from E084DAB9 (belonging to previous maintainer Michael Rutter) to 381BA480 (current maintainer Johannes Ranke)

Comment: Update 3/22/2017: Current public key is Michael Rutter 51716619E084DAB9

Comment: Thanks Chad. Still current as of 2018-05-15

Comment: as of today key for 3.6.1 is Johannes Ranke FCAE2A0E115C3D8A

Comment: From where is this key found ?

Answer (score 45):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys KEYID
```

and replace KEYID with the number shown in the error message.

Comment: Exactly, because the key changed AGAIN, this time to `FCAE2A0E115C3D8A`. Your answer would always work!

Answer (score 18):

Thanks to [Philipp Burckhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1494708/philipp-burckhardt), I got it fixed.

Try this:

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key 51716619E084DAB9  
gpg -a --export 51716619E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: The 2nd link is no longer available.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a step-by-step answer that might be easier to follow.

1. Fetch the key (the last 8 digits in the warning message):

   ```
   gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-key E084DAB9
   ```

   The output should look like this:

   ```
   gpg: requesting key E084DAB9 from hkp server pgp.mit.edu
   gpg: key E084DAB9: public key "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" imported
   gpg: Total number processed: 1
   gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
   ```
2. Add the key (superuser access required):

   ```
   gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Update the repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

There should be no warning about the missing key now.

Comment: The mit keyserver fails sometimes. Replacing it with `keyserver.ubuntu.com` works.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same issue and the only solution I found, perhaps due to a firewall, was to use the helpful Y PPA Manager. The two steps below outline has worked on Ubuntu 15.04.

1) First install the Y PPA Manager:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

2) Then fetch missing keys by running the Y PPA Manager:

```
y-ppa-manager
```

> Click "Advanced"
>
> > Next, click "Try to import missing GPG keys"

Finally, update again to check if it works:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 4):

Much like others posted above, this one-liner seems to work well on Debian 6:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 381BA480

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options
--no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 381BA480 
gpg: requesting key 381BA480 from hkp server pgp.mit.edu 
gpg: key 381BA480: public key "Johannes Ranke (CRAN Debian archive) <jranke@uni-bremen.de>" imported 
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found 
gpg: Total number processed: 1 
gpg:      imported: 1
```

Comment: I'll add that sometimes the default port is blocked, so you have to specify getting the key over an unblocked port, like 80.  See: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem

`$ wget -q -O - https://archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc  | apt-key add`

Answer (score 1):

It had to use a longer identifier for the key.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

The issue seems to be a duplicated key ID on the server.
See the instructions from the [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) and more background info on [this post](https://rubuntu.netlify.app/post/changes-to-cran-ubuntu-webpage-regarding-apt-secure-key/) by Michael Rutter.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is to simply follow the instructions from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/. Run this as sudo:

```
# update indices
apt update -qq
# install two helper packages we need
apt install --no-install-recommends software-properties-common dirmngr
# add the signing key (by Michael Rutter) for these repos
# To verify key, run gpg --show-keys /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc 
# Fingerprint: 298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
wget -qO- https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc
# add the R 4.0 repo from CRAN -- adjust 'focal' to 'groovy' or 'bionic' as needed
add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"
```