# ubuntu xenial/ Release' no longer has a Release file. error in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

when i am updating with `sudo apt-get update`

I have to update this because some library are demanding a updated version, I have tried

a solution which i have mention in bottom side, but it doesn't work and gives an same error again and again

here is the error that I am getting.

````
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 

E: The repository 'https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.```

I found this problem [Here][1] , But it does not work for me


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255082/installing-r-from-cran-ubuntu-repository-no-public-key-error


please tell me the problem
````

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

First try adding the PPA of the repo you need.

If you go to [the repo](https://spout.ussg.indiana.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/) here.

**Add the PPA for the right version**(my example is for version

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:c2d4u.team/c2d4u4.0+
sudo apt-get update
```

Then add the repo url to the source.list.

**First, take a backup of your /etc/apt/source.list**

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/source.list /etc/apt/source.bak
```

**Replace This**

```
https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ Release
```

**With this**

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran40/
```

**In your /etc/apt/source.list**

Lastly try updating again.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

**Solution 2**

You might need to point apt-get to the archived repos.
I dont recognize your repo URL. From my experience If you are on a Xenial, your source list should not have bionic in it.

Have you tried these repositories?

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

**I hope you have a full backup of this server. From my experience replacing apt list with the wrong repos could break applications and the whole OS.**

Anyhow if it really is xenial repo you are after.

**First, take a backup of your /etc/apt/source.list**

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/source.list /etc/apt/source.bak
```

**Next copy and paste the repos i provided above.**

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/source.list
```

Paste the list in with the nano editor or your prefered editor.

Save the file with: ctrl+O

Close the file with: ctrl+X

Lastly try updating again.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Get `sources.list` from: https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/generate.php

Replace to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the downloaded file.

Then update using:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```