# apt cannot find public key 6DB5542C356545CF

Tags: security, heroku, apt, heroku-cli

Ran `sudo apt update` and got the following error for the Heroku repository that indicates failed signature verification and missing public key `6DB5542C356545CF`. The only information about this key I can find online is in Japanese or Korean, neither of which I understand, and translating them does not reveal any particularly useful information. I am concerned this could be a MITM attack, does anyone have any information or advice?

The full error message:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6DB5542C356545CF
W: Failed to fetch https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/./InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6DB5542C356545CF
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: [apt cannot find Heroku-cli public key 6DB5542C356545CF #1812](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/1812)

Comment: Just take a look: [No Public Key Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260634/10846570)

Answer (score 3):

Execute:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6DB5542C356545CF
```

or

```
curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt/release.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I should have been clearer in my question, I'm trying to find out _why_ this happened, it's easy to find solutions, but generally I don't like to just copy/paste code from the internet into my terminal without understanding what caused the problem in the first place.

Comment: @diatomicDisaster you are right, blind importing of PGP keys could result in installing malicious code.